# How To Enable Optimization Level in Unity 5.3.1. For WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making webgl build using Unity 5.3.1 & want to enable optimizations level for webgl.But i am seeing unity giving this feature for only development build mode.

Please let me know how i can enable optimization level in Unity 5.3.1.